# Terminology about the tensorial represention of a group

Tags: terminology, group-theory, representation-theory

This could be extremely trivial but i need to be sure I am not wrong.
I am encountering many times statements where the author says

> "Tensors are examples of representations for the Lorentz group".
>    (A modern introduction to quantum field theory, Michele Maggiore. Page 20).

It is clear to me that if I consider for example $SO(3)$, or $SO(3,1)$ I can think to act its transformations on scalars, vectors or event tensors and find the related representations.
So the previous sentence isn't an abuse of notation? I think I should say a tensorial representation of the Lorentz group is a representation that acts on tensors, is this correct?

I found a similar problem in a more physical context. With the statement

> "$d$ degenerate eigenstates furnish a d-dimensional irreducible representation for the group $G$". 
>   (Group theory in a nutshelli for physicists, A. Zee. Page 163).

Here is the context. Given a hamiltonian $H$ and its symmetry group $G$, then $H$ is invariant under the transoformations $T$ of $G$
$$H=T^{-1}HT\rightarrow HT=TH$$
considering the eigenvalue problem $$H\psi=E\psi$$ $$H(T\psi)=TH\psi=E(T\psi)$$
so we can see that $T$ doesn't mix states of differents eigenspaces, and the eigenspaces are like invariant subspaces of the Hilbert space from the point of view of $T$. Using a suitable basis for the Hilbert space I can show $T$ has a block diagonal form and hence is reducible. But considering $H$ just on a specific eigenspace $V_E$ then the hamiltonian has the form $H=EI$ and following from Schur's lemma I can say that the specific block associated to $V_E$ of the reducible representation of T is an irreducible representation. Is this what it is meant with the previous statment? That a correct choiche of the basis $\psi$ in the eigenspace showes me what is the irreducible representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A representation of a group $G$ is a pair $(\varphi,V)$ where $V$ is a vector space and $\varphi:G\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$ is a group homomorphism between the group $G$ and the set of invertible linear transformations over $V$. Sometimes authors call $\varphi$ the representations and sometimes authors call $V$ the representation.

You can say that the first way is fine since $\varphi$ carries information about the space it acts on. On the other hand the second one is, as you point out, an abuse of terminology. However, often (not always!) once $V$ is fixed, there is only one choice for $\varphi$, so it's fine.

For tensors, $V$ is the tensor product of $\mathbb{R}^n$ $\mathrm{rank}$ times and $\varphi$ is the unique homomorphism that makes $G$ acts on tensors in the usual way that we know.

For the Hamiltonian example you presented, $V$ is the eigenspace of energy $E$ and $\varphi$ is some unitary operator restricted to $V$, $U|_V$, that acts on the states and commutes with the Hamiltonian. Precisely because it commutes with it, we never go out of the eigenspace, so the operator $U$ can be restricted to $\mathrm{GL}(V)$.

By the way, you are using Schur's lemma backwards. It says that if $[H,U|_V]=0$ and the representation is irreducible, then $H \propto \mathbb{1}$ (which is true). *Not* the other way around. That means that $(U|_V,V)$ can still be a reducible representation if there are invariant subspaces. For example, suppose your Hamiltonian has degenerate energies for states with the same total spin $J = S+L$. Then if we look at energy eigenspaces and only care about spin $S$, and not $J$, we may find a direct sum of spin representations there.

Comment: So it is in both cases the same situation, I just idenitfy the representation homomorphism with the space on which the matrices of the general linear group acts.  Thanks a lot for the answer and for the precisation on Schurl's lemma.

Comment: I wouldn't say identify. It's more a [synecdoche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche): you refer to something by referring to a part of it instead of the whole.

Comment: Perfectly clear, thanks a lot